# Unable to get Element-ui component to display for Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, element-ui

I am trying to display a component in my sample project just to get it working before I start working on a full application.

I run on Debian 10 (Buster) and there is a compatibility issue with npm and node so I figured to get a newer version for npm (6.0.1) figuring this would help but same result. My node version is 10.15.2 by the way.

I did a google search and went on Youtube to find examples but everything online is for 5.7 or less and those do not work

in "resources/assets/js/app.js" I added:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vue from 'vue';
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';

Vue.use(ElementUI);
```

Note that it is necessary to add the line `import Vue from 'vue';` otherwise my `Vue.use` is not recognized. All examples online seem to miss this step for some reason.

I created my sample component

```
Vue.component('el-switch', require('./components/el-switch.vue').default);
```

And created a vue component in "resources/js/components/el-switch.vue" with the following code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <el-switch
            v-model="value1"
            active-text="Pay by month"
            inactive-text="Pay by year">
        </el-switch>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                value1: true,
                value2: true
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

In the default "welcome.blade.php" I added the following code:

```
<br>
Element-UI component:<br>
<br>
<div id="app">
   <el-switch></el-switch>
</div>
```

And at the bottom of my body I added the following script:

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

When I start my web browser I would expect to see the switch component that I used as an example but instead I do not see anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have two elements with same name.

Comment: Ok, thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Dit you also create a new Vue instance? new Vue({render: h => h(App)}).$mount('#App')